# Combine php array duplicate values

Tags: php, arrays

I have a php array that just like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product] => 2
            [price] => 30
            [qnty] => 1
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [product] => 2
            [price] => 30
            [qnty] => 1
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [product] => 1
            [price] => 250
            [qnty] => 1
        )
)
```

and I want to combine the duplicate values, add "**qnty**" index value and print that array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product] => 2
            [price] => 30
            [qnty] =>2
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [product] => 1
            [price] => 250
            [qnty] => 1
        )
)
```

How can i combine this array.  Please help me

Comment: Iterate over the array, check for duplicate items of the current, if so, remove the duplicates and increase `qnty`

Answer (score 1):

try the code below. I am assuming the your array name is `$products`

```
$merged = array();
  foreach($products as $product) {
  $key = $product['product'];

  if(!array_key_exists($key, $merged)) {
      $merged[$key] = $product;
  }
  else {
      $merged[$key]['qnty'] += $product['qnty'];
  }
}
 echo '<pre>';
 print_r($merged);
 exit;
```

Comment: hi, Thanks for the code. but i getting this error: **Warning: array_key_exists(): The first argument should be either a string or an integer**